# Python, `let`, `with`, local scopes, debug printing and temporary variables

Tags: python, debugging, with-statement, let, contextmanager

I'm trying to refactor a project targeting Python 3.6 and pytest. The test suite contains a lot of debug statements such as:

```py
print('This is how something looks right now', random_thing.foo.bar.start,
      random_thing.foo.bar.middle, random_thing.foo.bar.end)
```

The idea behind these statements is that if a test starts failing in future, we will have some context to help us track down what the problem could be. There's no need to test what the actual values are right now in that test, but once things start failing, having that information is important for further debugging.

I would like to avoid repeating `random_thing.foo.bar.` that many times. I could assign that to a temporary variable, but the code does not really *need* that variable available ever after. I'm not really worried about performance, but I have a strong preference for keeping the code "clean" -- and "leaking" these variable names rubs me the wrong way. There *is* a feature like this in other languages that I'm familiar with, so I'm wondering how to do this in Python.

I'm fluent in C++, where I would probably just put that debug print into an extra scope:

```cpp
{
  const auto& bar = random_thing.foo.bar;
  debug << "start: " << bar.start << ", middle: " << bar.middle << ", end: " << bar.end;
}
```

Given that [there are no anonymous blocks in Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0340/), is there a "Pythonic" way of avoiding this namespace clutter? I'm not really looking for opinions or a popularity contest, but for a review based on how people who have been doing Python longer than me perceive these approaches, so here are a few things that I tried:

### 1. Just add that damn variable and `del` it afterwards

Well, I don't like repeatedly doing stuff that a machine should do for me.

### 2. `with` statement and [`contextlib.nullcontext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nullcontext)

In Python, there is no new scope with the `with` statement, so this leaves that `opj` variable available through locals:

```py
>>> import os
>>> import os.path
>>> import contextlib
>>> with contextlib.nullcontext(os.path.join) as opj:
...   print(type(opj))
... 
<class 'function'>
>>> print(type(opj))
<class 'function'>
```

### 3. `with` statement and Vladimir Iakovlev's [`let` statement decorator](https://nvbn.github.io/2014/09/25/let-statement-in-python/)

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from inspect import currentframe, getouterframes

@contextmanager
def let(**bindings):
    frame = getouterframes(currentframe(), 2)[-1][0] # 2 because first frame in `contextmanager` is the decorator  
    locals_ = frame.f_locals
    original = {var: locals_.get(var) for var in bindings.keys()}
    locals_.update(bindings)
    yield
    locals_.update(original)
```

The code looks awesome to me:

```
>>> a = 3
>>> b = 4
>>> with let(a=33, b=44):
...     print(a, b)
... 
(33, 44)
>>> print(a, b)
(3, 4)
```

It does not `undef` a variable which was not defined before, but that's easy to add. Is manipulating the stack in this way a sane idea? My Python-fu is limited, so I'm torn between seeing this as uber-cool and uber-hackish. Is the final result "reasonably Pythonic"?

### 4. A wrapper around `print` with `**kwargs`

Let's use `**kwargs`:

```py
def print_me(format, **kwargs):
    print(format.format(**kwargs))

print_me('This is it: {bar.start} {bar.middle} {bar.end}', bar=random_thing.foo.bar)
```

This is good enough, but [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) can contain actual expressions, such as:

```py
foo = 10
print(f'{foo + 1}')
```

I would like to keep this functionality. I understand that [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) cannot really support this because of security implication of passing user-defined inputs.

Comment: I'm not sure what worries you about `x = random_thing.foo.bar`. Any hack/workaround for doing so will be far more taxing on the machine/system than just creating it. `random_thing.foo.bar` already exists in memory. Creating one more reference to it can't harm anything

Comment: @DeepSpace -- I tried to answer that in an edit. I'm not really worried about runtime cost or memory usage, it's the "tidiness" of the code and my subjective feeling. It just rubs me the wrong way (and I can imagine scenarios where these *could* be harmful, given the dynamic nature of Python, but I'm rather hand-wavy at this point...).

Comment: @DeepSpace - If `x`isn't deleted, then you've got an extra reference to `random_thing.foo.bar` hanging around which changes the test.

Comment: `bar = random_thing.foo.bar` is the easiest solution by far.  You are only creating a reference to the object, of which `bar` reference will cease to exist as the code proceeds out of scope, a `del bar` is not even necessary.  Given that you have multiple objects you might want to reference to - #4 would be my approach using f-strings and passing the test object in the statement.  Code tidiness is one thing, but if it ends up making the code less readable then it's doing you more harm than good.

Comment: @tdelaney Why is there a reference-counting test to begin with? How does one more reference changes the test? If it's a problem, do `del x` after that. Using any magic just to not create a reference sounds like shooting yourself in the foot

Comment: @DeepSpace - suppose the test reassigns `random_thing.foo.bar` - or maybe it doesn't do that today but some refactoring does it in the future. Taht extra reference held by the test changes things. You are stuck with `del x` everywhere and OP doesn't want that.

Comment: I think the alternatives all have issues (I would favor calling a helper function) so you just grin and bear it.

Comment: @tdelaney *reassigning*  `random_thing.foo.bar` does not affect `x`

Comment: @tdelaney if you are reassigning `random_thing.foo.bar` then for all intents and purposes you are testing a different object, which should not be `x`.  Unless the question here is how to use *one* reference point to test *multiple* different objects.

Comment: @DeepSpace  - Yes it does. If `x` keeps the object ref count from going to 0 when `random_thing.foo.bar` is reassigned, then the object delete code doesn't run at the moment of reasssignment and your test code has changed the environment. Obviously you don't care about this sort of thing and you and I will never agree.

Comment: @tdelaney If your tests care about references you have bad tests. A test should not care about number of references to objects. If a test fails because you have `x = random_thing.foo.bar` then there are  bigger problems with the codebase than worrying about repeatedly typing `random_thing.foo.bar`.

Comment: @r.ook - You seem to be struggling with this too. Objects are deleted when their ref counts go to zero. Good test code worries about this sort of thing. I counted 275 implementations of `__del__` in the python stdlib, just the .py files, ignoring the C files. That's 275 places where code operates differently depending on when del is called.

Comment: @tdelaney The conversation is losing its focus here - OP is not even concerned about reference counting or memory allocation.  They very explicitly stated they just *don't like* having that extra name there.  Subjective feelings aside, I still think it's the most objective approach.

Comment: @tdelaney Unless you are writing tests for GC, I highly doubt the truthness of "Good test code worries about this sort of thing". In Python, you don't even know when the GC executes. Why would your test care about that? I have never seen a module test that counts references. Do you an open-source example? And, as r.ook mentioned, OP does not even care about ref counts.

Comment: @r.ook - completely false. OP has a subjective concern... the references seem untidy. But there is an objective concern. You don't care about it, fine. But don't pretend otherwise. I am done with this argument.

Comment: @tdelaney lol, how did we arrive to cyclic references now? BTW, the reference count for `x` would have been reduced when the individual test method is finished. Anyway, this discussion is fruitless since OP does not even care about reference counts. They wrote themselves `"I'm not really worried about runtime cost or memory usage"`

Comment: @DeepSpace _In Python, you don't even know when the GC executes_

Comment: @tdelaney You have a point about reference counting, but that is really not the concern from OP, which makes it irrelevant.  Regardless, then the best answer is really, *just use the actual reference*.  After all, explicit is better than implicit, and readability is king.  All OP is asking for here is code fluff.

Comment: I would say that the reference counting concern is one more reason to care about this. I wanted to avoid relying on GC corner cases in my motivation to make stuff easier to understand.

Comment: Just make the variable. If one extra local variable bothers you this much, I have to wonder how you feel about Python's function-scoped `for` loop targets - every time you use a `for` loop, that loop variable hangs around for the entire rest of the function.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica "not happy", of course :).

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to just create the variable and leave it there, or `del` it afterward if it really bothers you that much.

---

`with` is not a viable approach. Particularly, that `let` thing is **completely broken** in multiple ways.

The most important way it's wrong is that **modifying `f_locals` is undefined behavior**, but this isn't immediately apparent in tests due to the other bugs. Two of the other bugs are that the `2` controls something completely unrelated to what the author thought, and the `[-1]` is indexing from the wrong end. These bugs cause the code to access the "root" stack frame, the one at the start of the stack, instead of the frame the author wanted. Finally, it has no handling for actually clearing variables - it can only set them to `None`.

If you [test it with a function](https://ideone.com/MKtcOQ), you'll find that it doesn't work:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from inspect import currentframe, getouterframes

@contextmanager
def let(**bindings):
    frame = getouterframes(currentframe(), 2)[-1][0] # 2 because first frame in `contextmanager` is the decorator  
    locals_ = frame.f_locals
    original = {var: locals_.get(var) for var in bindings.keys()}
    locals_.update(bindings)
    yield
    locals_.update(original)

def f():
    x = 1
    with let(x=3):
        print(x)

f()

print(x)
```

Output:

```
1
None
```

The `3` isn't visible in the code that should have seen it, and there's an extra `None` hanging around in the wrong scope afterwards.

There's no good way to get the functionality you want out of a `with` statement. Default `with` scope rules don't do what you want, and Python doesn't provide a way for a context manager to mess with the locals of the code that called it.

---

If you really hate that variable and you don't want to use `del`, the closest thing to a good option might be to use a Javascript-style immediately-invoked lambda:

```
(lambda x: print(f'start: {x.start}, middle: {x.middle}, end: {x.end}'))(
    random_thing.foo.bar)
```

I think this option is a lot worse than just assigning `x` the normal way, but maybe you think differently.

Comment: Thanks for spotting these bugs in `let`. Do you have a reference for the undefined behavior you mentioned? The first page of Google hits yielded no relevant results for me (perhaps I don't know what to search for; I'm not really familiar with any standard definition of Python's behavior).

Comment: @JanKundrát: The closest thing I can provide is a reference to the docs for [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals), which include the following warning: "The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter." `f_locals` is the `locals()` dict for a given stack frame.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of fun with it.

```
#Fake object structure 

class Bar:
    start="mystart"
    middle= "mymiddle"
    end="theend"

class Foo:
    bar = Bar

class Rando:
    foo = Foo


random_thing = Rando()

#Fake object structure 

def printme(tmpl, di_g={}, di_l={}, **kwargs):
    """ use passed-in dictionaries, typically globals(), locals() then kwargs
        last-one wins.
    """

    di = di_g.copy()
    di.update(**di_l)
    di.update(**kwargs)
    print(tmpl.format(**di))


bar = random_thing.foo.bar

printme('This is it: {bar.start} {bar.middle} {bar.end}', globals())
printme('This is it: {bar.start} {bar.middle} {bar.end}', bar=Bar)

def letsdoit():
    "using locals and overriding bar"
    bar = Bar()
    bar.middle = "themiddle"
    printme('This is it: {bar.start} {bar.middle} {bar.end} {fooplus}', globals(), locals(), fooplus=(10+1))    


letsdoit()
```

#### output:

```
This is it: mystart mymiddle theend
This is it: mystart mymiddle theend
This is it: mystart themiddle theend 11
```

Comment: Yeah, this is my option #4.

Comment: more or less, yeah.  that's what I would pick anyway.  I've done a lot of this type of logging/debug support and, for me, a key determinant is that it needs to be cheap to write/maintain (a flag to turn it off is nice too).  that's why I put in the locals/globals.  in fact, I'd probably go a bit further and pass only a string header "this is it:", along with say a `show="bar.start,bar.middle,bar.end",  split, then build the template string dynamically rather than writing it by hand.  My $.02 anyway.